# Free (as in beer) Cisco VPN equivalent for Linux client

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

I have several customers that I connect to via Cisco VPN Client (v5 if that matters) on Windows. I'm doing some tidying up and was wondering if there was a simple way to be able to connect to the same vpn endpoints from a Linux desktop.

It is our clients who have purchased Cisco equipment so I can't simply download the Cisco Linux client without a login.  If need be I can ask one of our clients to do the download but I'd rather sort this myself if possible.

After some digging round in ServerFault I found some references to vpnc.  Is this a suitable solution or are there some additional hoops to jump through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't usually post links to my own material, but I happened to write a [quick tutorial on vpnc](http://kamilkisiel.blogspot.com/2008/10/connecting-to-cisco-ipsec-vpn-from.html) on exactly this topic. Maybe it will be of use to you.

Comment: Dead link.  Can you update it?

Answer (score 2):

VPNC worked great for me.  I have never installed it myself, but it came pre-installed on Fedora 10 and 11.  I loaded the .pcf file like it were any other client (using the NetworkManager frontend) and fired up the connection.

Comment: how is it that whenever I ask what I think will be a hard question someone has a quick concise answer up within minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I use vpnc all the time trough kvpnc graphical interface co connect to a 3005 vpn concentrator. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try out the Shrew [Soft VPN Client](http://www.shrew.net/) ? It is free and available for both Windows and Linux.